# SSH - Using grep with special chars

Tags: ssh, grep, escaping

I'm trying to search some string on some files but I didn't find the good combination.

I want to use this command but I have an error in my syntax

```
grep  -r -H "<?php $GLOBALS[" /var/www/vhosts/
```

I want to search (via SSH) the string `<?php $GLOBALS[` on the files under /var/www/vhosts

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: it gives me a lot of unattended results. Cyrus's command is working fine. Thanksfor him

Comment: First thing: because you're using double quotes, your variable `$GLOBALS` is being expanded by the shell, so your grep command looks like `grep -r -H "<?php ["` (assuming you don't have such a variable defined in your shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
ssh user@host "grep -r -H '<?php \$GLOBALS\[' /var/www/vhosts/"
```